# LINQ : how do I simplify this query?

Tags: linq

How do I simplify this query?

```
var cookieList = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.ToList()
                .Select(cookie => new { cookie.Key, cookie.Value })
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(cookie => $"{cookie.Key}={cookie.Value}")
                .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var cookieList = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies // assumed IEnumerable otherwise .ToList is ok
                .Select(cookie => $"{cookie.Key}={cookie.Value}")
                .ToList()
```